# Add UITableView as viewForFooterInSection within a tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to add a loop of custom UIViews at the end of a previous tableView so I have two consecutive lists inside the same VC.

As I wanted the scroll to be global and not into two separates tableViews I tried to add content with a loop inside viewForFooterInSection method.

As you can imagine it didn't go as planned. The debugger doesn't give me any errors but my UI does not show anything too. I'm wondering if someone would know how it could be achieved.

Here is a screen of what I want to do:
[image]

As you can see it should be two consecutive tableViews but I don't want them to be scrolling apart from each other. I want the flow of the page to be one big scroll.

Here is my code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let footerView = UIView()
        self.getBestUsers( completion: { // API call
            self.bestUsers.enumerated().forEach { (index, user) in // Loop
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let footer = self.debateList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bestUsersBox") as! UserBox
                    self.tableView.tableFooterView = footer
                    footer.setNeedsLayout()
                    footer.layoutIfNeeded()
                    footer.frame.size = footer.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
                    footer.userBoxView.user = user
                    footerView.addSubview(footer)
                    footer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                    footer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                    footer.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                    footer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                }
            }
        })
        footerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return footerView
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pN9u.png
```

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea... or, it's not at all clear what you want to do. You have a table with *multiple sections*? And you want "several rows of something" inside the footer view for each section? Or, from the way you describe things in your question, do you have just **one** section and you want "several rows of something" starting after the last row in your table?

Comment: Not very clear but I think what you're saying in second might be what I want. To be clear: one "section" with particular data and a load more button at the end, and then another "section" with different data that stays after the loading button whatever length the first section is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out how to achieve what I wanted. Sorry if this wasn't clear.

I just used two different sections to add my content with different sources :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let loadCell = debateList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "loadMore", for: indexPath) as! LoadMore
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let debateCell = debateList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "debateBox", for: indexPath) as! DebateBox
            if trendingDebates.count > 0 {
                if (indexPath.row == trendingDebates.count) {
                    loadCell.buttonTapCallback = {
                        self.loadMoreDebates()
                    }
                    if trendingDebates.count < totalItems {
                        return loadCell
                    } else {
                        return UITableViewCell()
                    }
                } else {
                    let currentDebate = trendingDebates[indexPath.row]
                    debateCell.debateBoxView.debate = currentDebate
                    return debateCell
                }
            }
        } else {
            let userCell = debateList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bestUsersBox", for: indexPath) as! UserBox
            userCell.userBoxView.user = bestUsers[indexPath.row]
            return userCell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```